# Creating a new string from the 5th character of every line in a .txt file

Tags: python, string, file, indexing, text

The function must return a string created by concaatenating the 5th character from each line into one string. Can you tell me what I am doing wrong?

Example:

```py
fifthchar("input.txt") ->  skzke akeaa4
```

```py
def fifthchar(filename):
    newstring = ""
    file = open(filename, 'r')
    for line in filename:
        newstring = newstring + line[4]
    file.close() 
    return newstring
```

Comment: Please note that 1) we don't have `input.txt`, so your example tell us nothing, and 2) we don't know what's not working because you haven't told us what you've observed that leads you to believe there's a problem.

Answer (score 3):

You need to edit the for loop, you are iterating through the string instead of the document. file instead of filename.

```
file = open(filename, 'r')
for line in file:
    newstring = newstring + line[4]
```

Answer (score 0):

One issue with your code is that it doesn't check the length of the current line. This will cause issues if the line doesn't actually have 5  characters in it. You also need to remember that a `\n` also counts as a character. Try this:

```
newstring = ""
for line in filename:
    stripped_line = line.rstrip()
    if len(stripped_line) >= 5:
        newstring = newstring + stripped_line[4]
```

Comment: @don'ttalkjustcode what bug is that? OP does not provide an error and my answer fixes the one I mentioned

Comment: *One issue with your code is that it doesn't check the length of the current line.* There is no current line. `filename` is not a file, it's a string.